# Load a joomla module in an external php page

Tags: php, joomla, module, external

I'm using Joomla 3.

I would like  to add one of my joomla modules to a separate(from joomla) PHP page. is this possible?

From what I could find online, I need to call the joomla framework and then ??????? and then it works.

```
<?php define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise(); 


?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


</head>

<body>


                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-22" style="none" />



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can look at the error.php page for an example of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It's Possible

- Initialize Joomla Framework (From Joomla 3.4.1 index.php)

  ```
  define('_JEXEC', 1);

  if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php'))
  {
      include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';
  }

  if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
  {
      define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
      require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
  }

  require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

  $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
  $app->initialise();
  ```
- After initializing you can call your module position using `JHtml`

  ```
  echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', '{loadposition position-22}');
  ```